# Retrieve data from a website

Tags: c#, web, screen-scraping

I want to grab a set of data from a site into my C# application. I've referred to some sites and articles using the WebClient class.

But the problem is the data I want is in a news bar made using flash. Is it possible to grab the data from it? The data in it also keeps on updating as well.

Comment: Do you have a legal right to use the data that you are attempting to scrape?

Comment: wht im trying to get is the stock market updates of the companies

Comment: I'm nearly 100% sure that, if you're supposed to use the data in your application, there's an API available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the Yahoo approach?  The below project does just that.

> It is easy to download stock data from Yahoo!. For example, copy and
>   paste this URL into your browser address:
>   http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=YHOO+GOOG+MSFT&f=sl1d1t1c1hgvbap2.
>
> Depending on your Internet browser setting, you may be asked to save
>   the results into a filename called "quotes.csv" or the following will
>   appear in your browser:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/StockQuote.aspx?display=Normal

Answer (score 0):

It is unable to grab a data from Flash.

One possible solution is that, if you dig into embed tag at the Flash object or find some url or rss that looks to be consumed by the flash, you can read that by WebClient or (hopefully) XmlReader.

Comment: Yeah - and can install Fiddler and run the site in the browser to find out where the data used by the flash app is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I was looking into it more and i found out that its a news ticker which i want to get data from. but still since its a flash object i think the best way is to find info feed for the ticker.